# How can I travel from Narita to Haneda airport, visiting Shibuya in between?

Tags: public-transport, tokyo, nrt, hnd

I arrive at Narita airport (NRT), want to go to Shibuya then to Haneda Airport (HND) how can I get to these places in one day?

Comment: I am confused. One day? Even the cheapest/slowest transit from Narita to Shibuya takes but 1:35 and from Shibuya to Haneda 57 minutes. Why is this question about one day?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I was not sure if I could go to Shibuya station from NRT were I arrive then go from Shibuya station to HND to take a flight out that night.  I only have a 6 hr layover that is why I mentioned "in one day"

Comment: Try http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Tokyo-Narita-Airport-NRT/Shibuya and http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Shibuya/Tokyo-Haneda-Airport-HND .

Comment: If you only have 6 hrs you barely have enough time for a transfer. If you have your bags checked through and the ongoing airline allows online check-in you may get away with having to be at the check-in counter 90 mins before your flight but you would likely only have 1.5-2hrs max if you managed to get to Shibuya and then tried to get to Haneda. Assuming movement times of 30 mins at airports, NRT (30mins to get out) + 100 mins train to Shibuya (similar for the bus) + 60 mins for train / bus to Haneda + 60 mins check-in / customs / immigration + 45mins ...cont.

Comment: cont. ...(you have to be at the gate as boarding for your flight commences). That leaves you a shakey hour at best. This assumes you have no problems with connections / traffic / navigating the confusing street and underground layouts of Tokyo. Best to err on the side of caution and give it a miss.

Comment: The Wandering Coder, thank you so much for the information

Answer (score 3):

It's **possible**, but you're not going to have a lot of time if you only have 6 hours to do it in, and I would not attempt this if you have a lot of bags to drag around.

Narita to Shibuya is about 80 minutes by Narita Express, although beware that [not all N'EX trains stop at Shibuya](http://www.eki-net.com/pc/jreast-shinkansen-reservation/english/wb/common/timetable/e_nex_u/index.html), meaning you may have a wait of up to 30 minutes.  There are other options (bus, connecting trains, etc), but none are meaningfully faster.

From Shibuya to Haneda, there are at least three different ways:

1. Easiest: [Limousine Bus direct](https://www.limousinebus.co.jp/en/platform_searches/index/3/128), every 30-60 min, just under an hour (assuming no traffic)
2. Fastest: JR Yamanote Line to Shinagawa, transfer to Keikyu to airport, total ~36 min.  Beware that Shinagawa is a large station and finding the right train may be challenging.
3. Most fun: JR Yamanote Line to Hamamatsucho, transfer to Tokyo Monorail to airport, total ~44 min.  This transfer is much easier, as the station is small and all monorails go to the airport, and the views from the monorail are great.

I'd allocate at least 3 hours in travel time alone.  Add in one hour at Narita for immigration etc and another at Haneda for check-in etc (are you flying domestic or int'l?), and that leaves you with **around one hour actually in Shibuya**.

Comment: Barely enough time for a coffee, if the 15 minute wait at Starbucks is anything to go by.